# How can I install connector config in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is there any other way to deploy connector config rather than POSTing connector config to kafka connect REST api? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#tasks

I am thinking of any form of persistent approach like a volume or s3, where connect during bootstrap would grap those configs would be great. Don't know/can't find if thats anywhere available.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API is the only way.

You can use abstractions like Terraform or Kubernetes resources, however, which wrap an HTTP client.

If you use other storage, that'll require you to write extra code to download files and call the REST API.